# Asynchronous HttpClient using libev

Tags: httpclient, libevent, libev

I'm writing a web server using libebb (http://tinyclouds.org/libebb/) and libev. I'm looking for an async httpclient that uses the libev event loop.

I'd like it to support Http 1.1 (pipelining, keep-alives, etc).

I hope this isn't a dumb question.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an HTTP client I made using libev and C++:

https://github.com/jspotter/evhttpclient

Feel free to pull/contribute.